# Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, rbenv

I am trying to run bundle on 2.1.10 ruby version. using rbenv and my local and global is both ruby 2.1.10 but everytime i try to server or bundle it says.

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.10
```

what would be the best possible way to fix or figure out the problem.

Comment: For the current project, i can only work with Ruby 2.1.10

Comment: "or figure out the problem" - the problem is that your current ruby is not 2.1.10. Use rbenv to install and switch to ruby 2.1.10 before running bundle

Comment: In my Gemfile & .ruby-version, i have Ruby 2.1.10. My rebenv local & global as well my ruby -v is 2.1.10. I want to run this project on ruby 2.1.10

Comment: @SergioTulentsev currently i have ruby 2.1.10 installed but i am still getting the error.

Comment: I cant even check rails -v. It gives me error as well. Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.10

Comment: What't the output of `ruby -v`? If it's 2.3.3 then you need to switch your ruby with rbenv. You can run `rbenv local 2.1.10` to set the ruby version in your current app to 2.1.10.

Comment: @FaisalMukhtar I think it's quite clear what the error is, so the real question here is **what exactly have you tried so far**?? You must be mistaken in thinking that the ruby version is `2.1.10`, because the error clearly states otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rvm use 2.1.10` if you used rvm to install ruby

if it is not installed it will give you the instructions to do it:

```
Required ruby-2.1.10 is not installed.

To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.1.10"'
```